# How can I define an equipotential surface/volume in FEniCS?

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, fenics, poisson-equation

I want to solve electrostatic problem for potential.  Charge density and medium permittivity are known, so is the potential of a grounded surface.  I know how I can implement that.

But I would like to add an ideal conductor (of unknown potential) to the system.  How can I introduce an equipotential surface/volume?  I guess setting permittivity to infinity is not a feasible option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not easily fit into a PDE formulation because it is a nonlocal constraint. But for all practical aspects, choosing a very large permittivity is usually good enough. Just choose it several orders larger than the rest of the domain.

Comment: I thought that should be something simple as all it requires is merging appropriate columns of the stiffness matrix. :/
Wouldn't such high difference in permittivity lead to numerical errors?

Comment: It increases the condition number and that increases the error. But if you choose a permittivity that is, say, $10^6$ larger than elsewhere, you should still be fine.